# VUEX Cordova take a photo from the camera end insert image src

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, cordova, mobile

my problem is that having access to the camera through navigator.device.capture.captureImage, after I took a photo, I get this res [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJsJD.png)

If I paste the protocol cdvfile sweat src it doesn't work.
i looked for solutions in Content-Security-Policy.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYBRr.png)

but it gave nothing at all except an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE0im.png)

add access to config.xml
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I0cd.png)

but nothing helps. I broke through to transform the path
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGm90.png)
it gave me only this result [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cun7H.png) and I also cannot use any address and display the photo in the place I need.

who can help? I will be very grateful

Comment: Please copy paste code/data instead of using images. It makes it hard to go through your post and help you with your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have already solved my problem

Comment: Then please delete this question or answer it thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.